# Run Angular 5 app as static website in browser without any server

Tags: javascript, angular

I have requirement to run Angular 5 application in browser by opening index.html file in browser manually. My client does not have any server. He just want me to send him a package(dist folder) and simply double click on index.html file to run the application as a website in the browser.

I am done with `ng build --prod --base-href ./` and i have files in my dist folder. I can't use any server Node/IIS because I can't ask my client to do install these servers as a prerequisite.

Comment: Try: 1.-use hashLocationStrategies https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy#hashlocationstrategy, 2.- change in your index.html the base tag for some like < script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');< /script>

Answer (score -2):

There is no way to do that. But you can install http-server packge on client's machine and just run http-server dist/ in your prod build directory.

`npm install -g http-server`

`http-server dist/`

hope this helps

Comment: To install `http-server` first I need to ask my client to install Node.js on their machine and then he/she would be able to install and use `http-server`. As i have mentioned in question i can't ask them to install entire server to run this.